# How to fix jquery click event in wordpress widget plugin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating wordress widget plugin...there are 4 checkboxes in my widget...when i click on first check box that will hide other 3 checkboxes.the problem is jquery's click event that is not working. also there is no error in console. when i click "Enable accessibility mode" in wordpress admin then click event works fine...how do i fix that issue?

Here is PHP plugin code:

```
function include_jscript() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugins_url('js/script.js',__FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jscript' );
```

Here is jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$('#chk_site').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
            $("#chkboxes").hide();
        else
            $("#chkboxes").show();
    }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="widget-content"> <br><label style="display:block;margin-bottom:6px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk_site" class="widget-zsearch-2-chk_site" name="widget-zsearch[2][chk_site]" value="">Display post type on site</label><div id="chkboxes"><label style="display:block;margin-bottom:6px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk_post" class="widget-zsearch-2-post" name="widget-zsearch[2][chk_post]" value="post">Search in Posts</label><label style="display:block;margin-bottom:6px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk_page" class="widget-zsearch-2-page" name="widget-zsearch[2][chk_page]" value="page">Search in Pages</label><label style="display:block;margin-bottom:6px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk_attachment" class="widget-zsearch-2-attachment" name="widget-zsearch[2][chk_attachment]" value="attachment">Search in Attachments</label><br></div> </div>
```

Comment: can you post the `html` code relevant to this?

Comment: no. i didn't post html

Comment: please do Omais.

Comment: i updated post with html...thanks Lakshan S

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code. For example, this is the correct syntax of a js if/else statement `if(argument){}else{}`. Here is a working solution,

```js
$(function(){
  $('.chkboxes').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).removeClass('chkboxes');
      $(".chkboxes").hide();
      }
    else{
      $(this).show();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='chkboxes'  type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chkboxes"  type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chkboxes"  type="checkbox"/>

<p> click any box to hide the others </p>
```

Comment: your code is also not working...as i mentioned my code is working when i enable accessibility mode from admin area of wordpress.

Comment: what do you want to achieve specifically?

Comment: i want to enable jquery click function without accessibility mode?

Comment: now it's working...the problem was checkbox id...i was binding click function by id selector that was not working but why? i don't  know. can u tell me? now i'm using class selector or specifying outer div id ( like: jQuery('#widget-zsearch-2 .chk_site').click(function(){});) for binding click function. it's working.